# How to Concatenate a variable into array value in PHP?

Tags: php

Dears,

How to concatenate a variable into array value? I Tried this way, but not works:

```
class Teste {
    public $test=1;

    public $rules2 = array('asdasd'.$test);
}
```

Error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your concatenation is correct. Your placement is not. You cannot reference other variables in class variable definitions.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me!